# Invalid Colum Name in authentication method of Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Im trying to login a user using the Identity provider of ASP.NET MVC 5 but i cannot do that.

Im getting this error:

```
"Invalid column name 'Email'.\r\nInvalid column name 'EmailConfirmed'.\r\nInvalid column name 'PhoneNumber'.\r\nInvalid column name 'PhoneNumberConfirmed'.\r\nInvalid column name 'TwoFactorEnabled'.\r\nInvalid column name 'LockoutEndDateUtc'.\r\nInvalid column name 'LockoutEnabled'.\r\nInvalid column name 'AccessFailedCount'.\r\nInvalid column name 'Email'.\r\nInvalid column name 'EmailConfirmed'.\r\nInvalid column name 'PhoneNumber'.\r\nInvalid column name 'PhoneNumberConfirmed'.\r\nInvalid column name 'TwoFactorEnabled'.\r\nInvalid column name 'LockoutEndDateUtc'.\r\nInvalid column name 'LockoutEnabled'.\r\nInvalid column name 'AccessFailedCount'.\r\nInvalid column name 'UserId'.\r\nInvalid column name 'UserId'.\r\nInvalid column name 'Email'.\r\nInvalid column name 'EmailConfirmed'.\r\nInvalid column name 'PhoneNumber'.\r\nInvalid column name 'PhoneNumberConfirmed'.\r\nInvalid column name 'TwoFactorEnabled'.\r\nInvalid column name 'LockoutEndDateUtc'.\r\nInvalid column name 'LockoutEnabled'.\r\nInvalid column name 'AccessFailedCount'."
```

Whats the problem, i need to use migrations for that?

Comment: it appears that whatever db you are using does not have the appropriate columns setup

Comment: @GSiry Im using the database generated by the Identity.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22817462/migrating-to-asp-net-identity-2-0-new-columns-not-being-created-in-aspnetusers