# await UserManager.CreateAsync looking for column that does not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

**Situation**

I had a working program which I updated needed to update the identity/login in method. So I updated from Identity 1 to version2 and I have been fixing errors as they come but I am currently stumped.

This is my Registration Code

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //try
        //{
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email,Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
```

**Problem**

The problem which is occurring is I am getting an `Invalid column name 'UserId'` on line `var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);`.
I am not entirely sure why this is occurring (or where this `UserId` is coming from, maybe from the old identity?) because when I place a breakpoint on the line the SQL shows the query as

```sql
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Email] AS [Email], 
    [Extent1].[EmailConfirmed] AS [EmailConfirmed], 
    [Extent1].[PasswordHash] AS [PasswordHash], 
    [Extent1].[SecurityStamp] AS [SecurityStamp], 
    [Extent1].[PhoneNumber] AS [PhoneNumber], 
    [Extent1].[PhoneNumberConfirmed] AS [PhoneNumberConfirmed], 
    [Extent1].[TwoFactorEnabled] AS [TwoFactorEnabled], 
    [Extent1].[LockoutEndDateUtc] AS [LockoutEndDateUtc], 
    [Extent1].[LockoutEnabled] AS [LockoutEnabled], 
    [Extent1].[AccessFailedCount] AS [AccessFailedCount], 
    [Extent1].[UserName] AS [UserName]
    FROM [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent1]
```

I humored the program by adding `UserId` to the AspNetUsers table and two things happened.

1. When I added it as a column I got the same error
2. When I renamed the primary key `Id` to `UserId` and made a normal field ID.
   Then the error I got was

   > InnerException = {"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'UserId', table 'dbo.AspNetUsers'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

**Conclusion**

What I am deducing from this is, somewhere that I cant find, on Registration, the program is trying to assign the GUID of a new user to `Id`, However, the database is trying to save it as `UserId`.

Would appreciate if I could get more assistance in solving this.

**Edit**

```
// You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection" , throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
    //protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    //{
    //    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    //    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
    //            .Property(p => p.Id)
    //            .HasColumnName("UserId");
    //}
}
```

Comment: Are you using code first? can you share your customized `IdentityDbContext`? Especially `ApplicationUser` as well

Comment: @Dongdong I have added it to the file, I believe it was database first.

Comment: So you are not using `OnModelCreating` now? it looks you changed column name to `UserId` (`HasColumnName("UserId")`), but didn't manage it back with database migration code

Comment: follow this official migration post to clearify your database to be totally same as your code. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/

Comment: No, When It was asking for `UserId` I attempted this while testing but it did not work. So I manually created the field in MS SQL to test.

Comment: check the file `ApplicationDbContextModelSnapshot` which is inside folder `Migration`. Carefully compare code here with your database. if there is any difference, which means you missed a step to migrate code, then follow above link to do migrations.

Comment: I do not have a `Migration` folder and trying to enable it by using `Enable-Migrations` is causing a new breed of errors.`Enable-Migrations : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.`

Comment: So now it's very clear, your code has mismatch with database, you need to fix migration issues, then you are good to go. but for any new errors, google seach can serve you well.  good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I finally solved this, 
First off, I reverted my database and did a new model.

I then updated my Identity Model in nugget package manager.
I then ran the app and it gave me a bunch of errors about missing columns.
***Crucial point*** , the last time I attempted this I created the columns manually in SQL then updated my mode, this may or may not have been my downfall.

Following This link https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/updating-asp-net-applications-from-asp-net-identity-1-0-to-2-0-0-alpha1/

I ran the Enable database command,and the update command to generate the sql queries.

In my case, the SQL that was generated was for some reason....wrong, it basically created tables I already had and did not address the missing columns, so running it of course gave an error.

Using this link [Migrating to Asp.Net Identity 2.0: new columns not being created in AspNetUsers table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22817462/migrating-to-asp-net-identity-2-0-new-columns-not-being-created-in-aspnetusers) and the answer from Chris Searles, I changed the code that was in the UP() and Down() function to his and that is what fixed my problem.

My issue might be unique to me but, hope it helps someone.

Comment: Faced the same problem. I used EFCore.NamingConvention nuget package to automatically use snake_case naming convention for columns, which also renamed AspNetCore.Identity tables (like `Id` -> `id`). Then if I try to use `UserManager` it looks for nonexisting column `Id`.